# Unable to access data on Intel "fake RAID" after failed Ubuntu update

Tags: linux, hard-drive, raid, data-recovery, mdadm

Recently I did an update of my Ubuntu, it seems to work at first but after restart it shows:

```
kernell ofset relocation range kernel panic not syncing: VFS
```

I try to use different older kernel from Grub but they all seems to have same problem

Ubuntu that I have updated was set up on Intel Rapid raid called "MainRaid" from Bios (Raid is reporting as working and healthy during post) also it start the Grub and try to load kernel (unsuccessfully)

I have download ubuntu 22 and make a bootable stick, from which (by using live version) I try to save data by copying it from my raid, problem is I can not make the raid become discoverable again

First I run `sudo fdisk -l`

I can see three disc two physically (members of the raid) and one virtual, this is my output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 238.47 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: ADATA SU800     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 3DF57144-44CA-4ABA-841F-56CAFB326190
Device       Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048      4095      2048    1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2     4096   1054719   1050624  513M EFI System
/dev/sda3  1054720 500113407 499058688  238G Linux filesystem
GPT PMBR size mismatch (500113671 != 500118191) will be corrected by write.
The backup GPT table is not on the end of the device.


Disk /dev/sdb: 238.47 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk model: ADATA SU800     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 3DF57144-44CA-4ABA-841F-56CAFB326190
Device       Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1     2048      4095      2048    1M BIOS boot
/dev/sdb2     4096   1054719   1050624  513M EFI System
/dev/sdb3  1054720 500113407 499058688  238G Linux filesystem

Disk /dev/mapper/isw_dcffbfjabb_MainRaid: 238.47 GiB, 256058200064 bytes, 500113672 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 3DF57144-44CA-4ABA-841F-56CAFB326190
Device                                      Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/mapper/isw_dcffbfjabb_MainRaid-part1    2048      4095      2048    1M BIOS bo
/dev/mapper/isw_dcffbfjabb_MainRaid-part2    4096   1054719   1050624  513M EFI Sys
/dev/mapper/isw_dcffbfjabb_MainRaid-part3 1054720 500113407 499058688  238G Linux f
```

First of all I tried to restore the raid:

```
root@ubuntu:~# mdadm --assemble --run /dev/test /dev/sdb /dev/sda
mdadm: /dev/sdb is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/sda is busy - skipping
```

I also try like this:

```
root@ubuntu:~# mdadm --assemble --run  /dev/sdb /dev/sda
mdadm: device /dev/sdb exists but is not an md array.
```

Than I try to stop the raid

```
root@ubuntu:~# sudo mdadm --stop /dev/mapper/isw_dcffbfjabb_MainRaid 
mdadm: /dev/mapper/isw_dcffbfjabb_MainRaid does not appear to be an md device
```

than try stop the discs:

```
root@ubuntu:~# sudo mdadm --stop /dev/sda
mdadm: /dev/sda does not appear to be an md device
```

than I try to mount the raid and/or individual discs

```
root@ubuntu:~# sudo mkdir /media/dysk1
root@ubuntu:~# sudo mount /dev/sdb /media/dysk1
mount: /media/dysk1: unknown filesystem type 'isw_raid_member'.

root@ubuntu:~# sudo mount /dev/mapper/isw_dcffbfjabb_MainRaid /media/dysk1
mount: /media/dysk1: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/isw_dcffbfjabb_MainRaid, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
 
root@ubuntu:~# sudo mount /dev/mapper/isw_dcffbfjabb_MainRaid-part3 /media/dysk1
mount: /media/dysk1: special device /dev/mapper/isw_dcffbfjabb_MainRaid-part3 does not exist.
```

I did also `root@ubuntu:~# sudo mdadm --assemble --scan` but i has no output

I did also

```
root@ubuntu:~# vgdisplay -v
  No volume groups found.
root@ubuntu:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : 
unused devices: <none>
```

Also for the reference I paste the output from `root@ubuntu:~# mdadm --examine /dev/sd*`

Output:

```
/dev/sda:
          Magic : Intel Raid ISM Cfg Sig.
        Version : 1.1.00
    Orig Family : c205c8e3
         Family : c205c8e3
     Generation : 00000093
  Creation Time : Unknown
     Attributes : All supported
           UUID : 64df4ed2:d29bea98:7891e9e2:8ecad7d4
       Checksum : 7df1adb5 correct
    MPB Sectors : 1
          Disks : 2
   RAID Devices : 1
  Disk00 Serial : 2J4120021118
          State : active
             Id : 00000004
    Usable Size : 500113408 (238.47 GiB 256.06 GB)
[MainRaid]:
       Subarray : 0
           UUID : a64d17c4:6122eb8d:38f49b03:c224e286
     RAID Level : 1
        Members : 2
          Slots : [UU]
    Failed disk : none
      This Slot : 0
    Sector Size : 512
     Array Size : 500113408 (238.47 GiB 256.06 GB)
   Per Dev Size : 500113672 (238.47 GiB 256.06 GB)
  Sector Offset : 0
    Num Stripes : 1953568
     Chunk Size : 64 KiB
       Reserved : 0
  Migrate State : idle
      Map State : normal
    Dirty State : clean
     RWH Policy : off
      Volume ID : 1
  Disk01 Serial : 2H3920011233
          State : active
             Id : 00000005
    Usable Size : 500113408 (238.47 GiB 256.06 GB)
/dev/sdb:
          Magic : Intel Raid ISM Cfg Sig.
        Version : 1.1.00
    Orig Family : c205c8e3
         Family : c205c8e3
     Generation : 00000093
  Creation Time : Unknown
     Attributes : All supported
           UUID : 64df4ed2:d29bea98:7891e9e2:8ecad7d4
       Checksum : 7df1adb5 correct
    MPB Sectors : 1
          Disks : 2
   RAID Devices : 1
  Disk01 Serial : 2H3920011233
          State : active
             Id : 00000005
    Usable Size : 500113408 (238.47 GiB 256.06 GB)
[MainRaid]:
       Subarray : 0
           UUID : a64d17c4:6122eb8d:38f49b03:c224e286
     RAID Level : 1
        Members : 2
          Slots : [UU]
    Failed disk : none
      This Slot : 1
    Sector Size : 512
     Array Size : 500113408 (238.47 GiB 256.06 GB)
   Per Dev Size : 500113672 (238.47 GiB 256.06 GB)
  Sector Offset : 0
    Num Stripes : 1953568
     Chunk Size : 64 KiB
       Reserved : 0
  Migrate State : idle
      Map State : normal
    Dirty State : clean
     RWH Policy : off
      Volume ID : 1
  Disk00 Serial : 2J4120021118
          State : active
             Id : 00000004
    Usable Size : 500113408 (238.47 GiB 256.06 GB)
/dev/sdc:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :     30431232 sectors at         2048 (type 0c)
/dev/sdc1:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   1851859059 sectors at   1936028272 (type 68)
Partition[1] :    538976288 sectors at   1330184192 (type 79)
Partition[2] :   1398362912 sectors at    538989391 (type 53)
Partition[3] :        21337 sectors at   1394627663 (type 49)
```

I have very important data on the disc and I'am determined to access it somehow, Did anybody have ide what is going on?